# Script for a multi-user webapp database connection

Tags: php, security, pdo, mysqli

I have the following working script which I use for my database connection for a multi-user webapp. I use a different database for the login, this script is called only after the user is successfully logged in. The login uses PDO.

I would like to know what I can do to

- make this more secure
- harder to fail

```
include('.dbinc.cred.inc.php');

try {
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . HOST_ONE . ';dbname=' . DB_ONE . '', USER_ONE, PASS_ONE);

$statement = $dbh->prepare("SELECT user_db, user_db_pass, user_db_user, user_name FROM databases WHERE user_name = :name");
$statement->execute(array('name' => $_SESSION['user_name']));

foreach ($statement as $row) {
   $user_db = $row['user_db'];
   $user_db_user = $row['user_db_user'];
   $user_db_pass = $row['user_db_pass'];
}

}
  catch (PDOException $e) {
print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
die();
}
$dbh = null;

$sql = new mysqli (HOST_ONE,$user_db_user, $user_db_pass,$user_db);
$sql -> set_charset ( 'utf8' );
if ($sql->connect_errno)
{echo "<script language=JavaScript>location.href='#ajax/account_setup.php';</script> ";}
```

Is it better to do this in 2 files, one for the user check, then define `HOST_TWO` and so on and include the first file in the second?

Why am I using PDO and then MySQLi? I do this (weird) thing because the whole app uses mysqli_ at the moment and I'm rewriting everything to PDO atm. But actually I need the MySQLi connection, though.

Comment: 2 simple things: `include` isn't a function, so you can drop the `()` around it; and you forgot to close the string with the filename on the `include`.

Comment: Thanks, edited it, only forgot the close ' in this question. The script is working, I'm mainly interested in security aspects of this script

Comment: I will tell 1 security problem: the password is stored without any kind of encryption. Even a simple xor cypher would be helpful. Both on the file and on the file `.dbinc.cred.inc.php` (hope I'm wrong) and on the database. And please, tell me you don't have all your databases' credentials stored in that database you are connecting with `PDO`.

Comment: You are welcome. One thing I would try too is fixing the indentation of your code. It helps a lot to read it. Other thing is that you are using a `print` then an empty `die()`. Put the output inside the `die()` function. It has the same effect but it's 2-in-1 and you use the `die()` function properly. And instead of using `foreach($statement as $row)[...]` replace it with `list($user_db,$user_db_user,$user_db_pass)=$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);` which should be a little faster. (About the `list()` piece: http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php )

Comment: Other improvements should be using `$statement->closeCursor();` after the `foreach` (on your current code, after the `list()` if you apply the improvements I told before) and removing the `$dbh = null;` and using `unset($statement, $dbh);` in the last line inside the `try{}` block.

Comment: You are welcome. When you have everything done, tell me the results, please.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Might want to move your comments to an answer before someone else does :)

Comment: He's got time, I'll only accept his - as he said it all

Comment: @jsanc623 You caught me on my gaming session. But I will make the answer now. It might take 10-20 minutes.

Comment: @jsanc623 I have posted as an answer, as you advised. I also added some tiny issues that his code had. Anything that isn't accurate or that escaped, feel free to correct.

Comment: No problem :) it's typically best, when comments are this drawn out to just create an answer

Comment: @michael I have made some important changes in the code, to reflect a possible security failure. Check it and drop a comment after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets tackle your code point by point:

## Security:

In terms of problems with security, I only see 1 problem:

There isn't any kind of encryption on your code.
From what I can see, you connect to a database that has all the password stored in plain text.
Any attacker that puts his hand on your file `.dbinc.cred.inc.php` will be very happy!

You can use the `mcrypt` list of function.
For documentation, you can check here: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php

**Edit**:

As @EliasVanOotegem pointed out on his comment, the collation isn't being set.
Appending `';charset=latin1'` to the string should do it.

If you are using a verson prior to 5.3.6, this will be ignored.
Instead, you must run `$dbh->exec("set names latin1");`
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4361485 
Luckly, PHP has a function to solve this kind of issue: `version_compare()`.
The version can be checked like this: `version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.6', '<')`
Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php

Now, you may ask: why not `utf8`?
The reason is that the default collation for most servers is in fact `latin1_swedish_ci`.
This means that a password like `aç$%dKeä` would be returned as scrambled data.
When you try to connect to the other database, using `mysqli_*`, the connection would be always rejected because the password would be different.

## The code itself:

On the code itself, I see some problems too.

Lets make some sections for it.

**The try{} block:**

Inside the `try{}` block, you have the following code:

```
foreach ($statement as $row) {
   $user_db = $row['user_db'];
   $user_db_user = $row['user_db_user'];
   $user_db_pass = $row['user_db_pass'];
}
```

This code isn't wrong, but this is useful when you fetch multiple rows from the database.
Another thing is that you only use this code to assign the variables to the values from the database.
You should use the `list()` constructor, using also the `$statement->fetch()` method.
The above code can be rewritten into this:

```
list($user_db,$user_db_user,$user_db_pass)=$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Documentation:
`list()` constructor: http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php 
method `$statement->fetch()`: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

**The `catch{}` block:**

Inside the `catch` block, you are using a `print` and on the next line you have an empty `die()`.
Removing the `print` and placing the text on the `die()` will have the same effect.
This code:

```
  catch (PDOException $e) {
print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
die();
}
```

Becomes:

```
catch (PDOException $e){
    die('Error!: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br/>');
}
```

This is not a *real* issue, but you are concatenating an empty string on the `PDO` initialization.
Here is the code:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . HOST_ONE . ';dbname=' . DB_ONE . '', USER_ONE, PASS_ONE);
```

Right after `DB_ONE`, you can remove that concatenation.

**Outside the try ... catch{}`:**

Outside the `try ... catch{}` block, you have this line:

```
$dbh = null;
```

This line, at the most, should be moved inside the `try{}` block, which is where you initialize the `PDO` object.

**Other observations:**

Your indentation is a little broken.
Indentation allows us to understand better where a block starts and finishes, and what is inside it.

---

This is just an observation, just for the paranoid people.

You fetch the data from the database but you don't free the result set.

You should run `$statement->closeCursor();` after you fetch your data.
You can check the documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php

After you don't need your variables, you should use `unset` just to free the memory, deleting the variables `$statement` and `$dbh`.
This way, I believe, you can skip the line `$dbh = null;` which is the example given in the php documentation, on the link: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php (go to example #3).

Another thing I noticed is the absence of the php tags.

---

Almost at the end of the code, you have this `echo`:

```
echo "<script language=JavaScript>location.href='#ajax/account_setup.php';</script> ";
```

The `language` attribute is deprecated and can be safely dropped. (Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-language )
This was useful in the times when VBScript was used for Internet Explorer, to diferentiate both languages.
Nowadays, you don't need this.
Another thing is that the value of the attribute isn't between quotes.
If you are paranoid about this, you can use the `type` attribute.
You can set the value `text/javascript`, being the final code like this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">location.href="#ajax/account_setup.php";</script>';
```

Documentation about the `type` attribute:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type

## The final code (security apart, reflecting the edit):

Applying all the changes, the final code will look like this:

```
<?php

    include('.dbinc.cred.inc.php');

    try {

        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' . HOST_ONE . ';dbname=' . DB_ONE . ';charset=latin1', USER_ONE, PASS_ONE);

        if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.6', '<'))
        {
            $dbh->exec('set names latin1');
        }

        $statement = $dbh->prepare('SELECT user_db, user_db_pass, user_db_user, user_name FROM databases WHERE user_name = :name');
        $statement->execute(array('name' => $_SESSION['user_name']));

        list($user_db, $user_db_user, $user_db_pass) = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

        $statement->closeCursor();

        unset($statement, $dbh);

    }
    catch (PDOException $e){
        die('Error!: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br/>');
    }

    $sql = new mysqli(HOST_ONE,$user_db_user, $user_db_pass,$user_db);
    $sql -> set_charset('utf8');
    if ($sql->connect_errno)
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">location.href="#ajax/account_setup.php";</script>';
    }

?>
```

As a micro-optimization, I swapped the quotes.
In terms of real-world usage, using `""` would make a negligible difference.
Use the quotes that you prefer, I simply prefer to save some CPU cycles.

Thanks to @EliasVanOotegem for spotting the safety issue regarding the lack of a specification on the used collation to connect to the database.
This is a serious issue because it changes the way that the parameters are escaped and avoids the use of special characters to 'nullify' the escapes, allowing other commands to run.
You can see how this attack is performed in here: http://hakipedia.com/index.php/SQL_Injection#Filter_Bypassing

Comment: This is one of the best, if not the best answer, I have gotten on SO so far. Thank you very much, the code looks like in your answer now (and pw and stuff are encrypted with mcrypt)

Comment: @michael Thank you. It gave me a bit of work and took longer than I though. Any inaccuracy you find, please edit the answer or leave a comment. I forgot to do something regarding that last `echo` that sends Javascript code. I will tackle it now.

Comment: I learn PDO since today, so your code examples were a nice help, too!

Comment: @michael PDO is a little difficult to learn in 1 day. But PHP has a decent documentation, in my opinion. I have made the changes. Check the information I have provided about the last `echo` on your code.

Comment: Yes, I think I'll need another day, or some more for that... Got the change. Once again, thank you very much for your time and help! Happy gaming!

Comment: @michael You are welcome. Just helping a fellow programmer in troubles with his code. And it will be hard to play decently, since the server is having troubles (I don't know, but EU servers are always a big slow pile of steaming ....). But well, any other questions you might have, you can always leave here a comment.

Comment: Cheers! I'm in Italy, I'm quite aware of bad internet connections...

Comment: @michael It isn't the internet connection. It is the server itself. The servers on this game are quite bad. Slow, unreliable, buggy and have tons of troubles with logins and client crashes.

Comment: @michael: There's another security issue here: you're not setting the collation in your `PDO` connection. Either use the `charset=utf8` in your DSN string, or pass an init-command. The DSN param is the preferred approach here

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Thank you for spotting that problem. I have made some important changes on the code, with an explaining what I did and why. If I said or did anything inaccurate, please leave here a comment or make an edit.